# Error while changing tabs in the backend

Tags: product, category, error, backend

When I try to switch in the backend between the tabs I get the page with this error:

> There has been an error processing your request

This happens not with all the tabs only with "Category" in the Products section.

Could you please show or help me to fix this?

Added link to the complete error log file, because its too long to post as is I've uploaded it to the cloud:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/grq42dzf794xhir/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Can you please check error log and share that error

Comment: Welcome to SE Matt, could you add full error msg here too.

Comment: You will find report number check same file name with given report number in var/report folder. Add report in question

Comment: Thank you! You are so fast its awesome, I added the error logfile.

Comment: i think you are using some extension for megamenu in this mega menu their is a attribute with id **sw_cat_hide_menu_item** for this attribute the source model is missing please check for a file ending with yesno.php in your extension.it might be some thing like  megamenu / category_attribute_source_block_yesno under model directory.

Comment: Can you please tell the name of extension you are using for megamenu.

Comment: Sure I can tell the names of the extensions, but I'm not using megamenu, only the sidebar navigation of codnitive, bannerslider and magenotification of magestore, I'm using also the hide prices module maybe thats it?

Comment: I had once installed a theme which used megamenu but I've completely removed it, but the description sw_ could only be from the theme sw=smartwave...

Comment: You're using Porto by Smartwave and you switched to a new theme right? Same case here. :D I just deleted all attributes that starts with sw_ in the eav_attribute table. Deleting it all will help prevent future issues in other pages in Magento admin. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occur when your *system have an attribute*  `sw_cat_hide_menu_item` and that attribute's *Source Model* is

```
megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_yesno
```

At past, there was **an extension** in which  `sw_cat_hide_menu_item` attribute's Source-Model class. 
was exits then you had remove this  class so that **Source model class is missing.**

For an solution,**you need to delete this attribute fro0m system**

So run this query:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE 'source_model'='megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_yesno'
```

Comment: it worked, finally the problem is fixed!

Comment: nice! Thanks for this. I did delete all tables created by smartwave (sw_). This problem only occured when you're using the famous Porto theme, then switched to another theme. :D